# Determine sin cos and tan from slope? NON CALCULator

Tags: trigonometry, education

I am used to finding this by drawing the triangle and knowing the angle measurement.
With the angle measurement i can find sin cos and tan.
But i dont have angle all I have is line.

I have put a scan but only because I could not show the angle $a$ and $b$
Not because I am hoping you do my homework!! This is a test revision sheet not something I have to turn it. I am not good at using graph drawing software. That is the only reason I scanned my sheet.

My question is Number $6$ where you can see my work begun
Consider line l containing points $O$ and $A$, and line $2$ the line containing points $O$ and $B$.
Line $1$ is: $3x-2y=0$   determine the values of $A$) $\sin a$, $\cos a$, $\tan a$
Line $2$ is: $x-4y=0$   determine the values of $B$) $\sin b$, $\cos b$, $\tan b$

So my thought is to put it in Yintercept form and get the slope. I notice that both lines have no $y$ intercept and begin at origin.

line one has slope of $3/2$
line two has slope of $1/4$

I know that slope is rise/run or $\sin/\cos$ or $y/x$

NOW
HELP #1 With this information how do i find angle? I know atan converts ratio to angle, but this is a NON CALCULATOR SECTION.
HELP #2 And am i right to say that to find angle all i have to do is plug in the unit circle information for the sin and cos of that particular angle and solve?

[image: revision for Thursday test]

Answer (score -1):

You have SOH CAH TOA written on your paper, and you figured out (I think) that rise and run correspond to two sides of the triangle. Use the Pythagorean theorem to find the third, and you're set.

Comment: So using rise of 3sq +run of 2sq = hypsq, so now i have numbers of 2, 3 and √15. So now i can use tan to find angle measurement. Tan converts angle to ratio, atan converts ration to angle. what is atan without my calc?

Comment: The question didn't ask for atan, so who cares?  (More seriously, they know that you don't know, so they don't expect you to know.)

Comment: the question DOES ask me to find the sin, cos, and tan of the angle a. from line 1 and the angle b from Line 2. So, I still haven't found the angle a yet? I thought the angle is found by atan. I know you dont want to give away homework, but this not homework it is revision for a upcoming test. I passed the calc one, but this is the NON calc, so I have to be very clear. thank you for your time.

Comment: I will quote myself: "You have SOH CAH TOA written on your paper".  Do you know why it is there?

Comment: yes, sine=opp/hyp, cos=adj/hyp and tan=opp/adj. sin=3/√15 rationalized to be √15/5  cos=2/√15 rationalized to be 2√15/15 and tan =3/2 or 1.5   I guess am confused by the little curvy arrow in the picture that refers to angle a. I thought i had to find the angle? So bascially if you can confirm that I did this all correct and not need to find the angle then I suppose I get it. I am only sorry that I didnt work it out myself. So all that is left to do is the other one with slope of 1/4 which i will do in the same way if this is right. thank you

Comment: The curvy angle is just confirming that angle A starts at the $x$-axis and goes to the line (as opposed to maybe just starting at line B).

Comment: what an idiot I am! a wavy line tripped me up. Makes sense though as when you use the calc they explicitly say find sin of angle 50 degrees etc. you click two buttons and done. so we did that first in class, so I kept looking for the angle. and have been frustated that I could not find one! a wavy line indeed. UGH